# Progress bar color in toolbar android?

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat

i am using progressbar in toolbar ,by default its loading Accent color,i want to customize the color of progressbar .i am using support library 22.0.0

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/my_aweseome_toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:indeterminate="true"

     />
```

so i tried to change progressbar color using setColor filter

```
  progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_spinner);
    progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF104D"),//Pink color
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

but i tried to set as pink ,but out put is some other different color.

```
progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE,android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)),
```

when i set as white color,its not even showing up..

Answer (score 4):

Use :

```
 <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
             />
```

use create progress.xml in your drawable folder :

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="720" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="8"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <size
            android:height="86dip"
            android:width="86dip" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="@color/blue"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this ,

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360" >

<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="20"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <size
        android:height="48dp"
        android:width="48dp" />

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="@color/tranparent"
        android:centerY="0.50"
        android:endColor="@color/red"
        android:startColor="@color/tranparent"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

Comment: What does `size` do here?  When I change it, my horizontal progressbar stays the same height no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN`. It works for me, at least with `SeekBar`.